# Visual Studio 12 - Checkin and Resolving Bug - Resolve not available

Tags: visual-studio-2012

While Checkin in with VS 12 - Team Explorer you can choose to which work items you like to check in. In one of our new projects it isn't possible to choose "Resolve" instead of "Associate" when checkin in a resolved bug. The bug isn't already resolved and is new.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only can resolve WorkItemTypes which has the corresponding action in the transition of the WorkItem.

Take a look at this workflow of a task from the Scrum template
[image]

The specified actions are not definied for a bug or backlog item.

This is a process thing because you resolve a task (the work you've done to resolve the bug) and the "doneness" of the bug/backlog item is verified by the product owner in the sprint review.

**Edit**

After searching a little bit it's clear that the process templates are getting updates too, see [Upgrade your 2012 team project from RTM to Update 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/04/04/upgrade-your-2012-process-template-from-rtm-to-update-2.aspx).

Comment: But it's possible in older projects. I've got this WorkItemType http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/ff731589.aspx

Comment: Where did the older projects come from? Are they migrated from previous versions? It is possible, that the projects use different project templates?

Comment: You're right. First I thought they use the same but they use a different template. But the behavior comes maybe from TFS 12 Update 2. Because the Bug-Template has some states I have never seen before.